# create a "listener" for an incoming socket stream that will contain a byte[] array

Tags: c#, sockets, stream, memorystream

I'm creating a socket server that needs to continuously listen for incoming messages from the connected clients.  Those messages will be sent in a byte[] array.  I had the server working great with a StreamReader but StreamReader only works with textual represenations of the data being sent...not byte[] arrays.

Here's what I had:

```
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(Client.GetStream());
        string line = "";
        while (true)
        {
            line = reader.ReadLine();
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(line))
            {
                parentForm.ApplyText(line + "\r\n");
                SocketServer.SendBroadcast(line);
            }
        }
```

I need to now convert that into a raw stream somehow that will convert the stream contents into a byte[] array but I can't seem to get a handle on it.

I tried this:

```
        while (true)
        {
            var bytes = default(byte[]);
            using (var memstream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                var buffer = new byte[512];
                var bytesRead = default(int);
                while ((bytesRead = reader.BaseStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
                    memstream.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
                bytes = memstream.ToArray();
            }
            //parentForm.ApplyText(bytes.Length + "\r\n");
        }
```

but as you might guess, the while(true) loop doesn't quite work how I need it to.  Can anyone help me with some code adjustment to make this work as I need it to.  It needs to continuously listen for incoming messages, then when a message is received, it needs to do something with that message (the byte[] array) then go back to listening again.

TIA

Comment: How exactly is it not working?  You have not given us enough information to work with.

Comment: What does the message look like? Is it fixed length? Is it length prefixed? Is it newline delimited (suggesting that it might actually be text)?

Comment: Your second piece of code doesn't have any notion of message. I mean, the while part will continiously read data until the client closes the connection, as it doesn't check for presense of delimiters in the incoming stream of data or anything.

Comment: Why use a MemoryStream at all? Why not just broadcast the buffer each time through the inner loop, like you were doing with the StreamReader?

Comment: @Cameron - that's the sort of answer I was looking for, but I"m not sure how to tackle that code-wise.  With streamreader.readline() it's easy because the whole line comes through in a chunk and I can use an if to determine if the line is not empty or null, but I'm not sure how to address it with an continual stream being pumped in....when does it end at which point, I would take the built byte array and do something with it.

Comment: @Christopher: But there is no difference -- before, you were reading until an endline. Now, you're reading a set number of bytes. You can check the number of bytes read to find out if it's empty or not. You already have chunks!

Comment: Still not clear if what you really "need" is a byte array. If the message is text (which to me is implied by the fact that you were using ReadLine), isn't a String what you really want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no need to convert anything. `GetStream()` returns a NetworkStream. See the sample Microsoft includes in the [NetworkStream.Read Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.networkstream.read.aspx). All you have to do is replace the `myCompleteMessage.AppendFormat("{0}", Encoding.ASCII.GetString(myReadBuffer, 0, numberOfBytesRead));` line with an appropriate storage mechanism.

Comment: awesome...I'm almost there.  Just not entirely sure how to fill the byte[] array instead of appending data to a string.  I tried creating a List<byte> and adding (myReadBuffer, 0, numberofBytesRead) thinking that was a byte, but it's not.

Comment: I ended up just plugging in a memorystring.write() and converting it to an array...may not be the cleanest solution, but it works. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I guess "listening continuously" is not task of reader its a task of listener. I ran into same problem when i was writing server using TcpListener. I am not sure what you want to do but i am posting solution for your "listening continuous" and reading into byte[] problem. I guess this code might help you:

```
TcpListener t = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Loopback, _port);
        t.Start();

        Console.WriteLine("Server is started and waiting for client\n\n");

        byte[] buff = new byte[255];
        NetworkStream stream;
        TcpClient client;
        while(true)
        {
            client = t.AcceptTcpClient();
            if (!client.Connected)
               return;

            stream = client.GetStream();
            while ((stream.Read(buff, 0, buff.Length)) != 0)
            {
                break;
            }

            if (0 != buff.Length)
                break;
        }
```